I purchased a 3D model online, need to get rid of duplicate geometry and replace with instances?
I recently purchased a 3D model online and there are A LOT of duplicate meshes. They are exactly the same, but are duplicates and not instances, this resulted in enormous file sizes and lag. I was wondering if someone could guide me as to how to approach this problem, however it is becoming apparent that scripting is likely the only efficient solution. In essence I would need to have write a script that would detect duplicate geometry (not sure how) find all duplicates in the environment and replace them with an instance in the exact same position and rotation.
I am someone with zero programming experience but I did ask Claude to write a script but it didn't work, for any of you coders out there perhaps it would be nice for you to figure out where the code went wrong:
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict

def find_duplicate_meshes(selected_obj):
    # Create a dictionary to store mesh data and their corresponding objects
    mesh_dict = defaultdict(list)

    # Get the mesh data of the selected object
    selected_mesh = selected_obj.data

    # Iterate through all objects in the scene
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.data == selected_mesh:
            # Store the object in the dictionary based on its mesh data
            mesh_dict[selected_mesh].append(obj)

    # Find duplicate meshes
    duplicate_meshes = [objs for objs in mesh_dict.values() if len(objs) > 1]

    return duplicate_meshes

def replace_with_instances(duplicate_meshes):
    for objs in duplicate_meshes:
        # Select the first object as the original
        original_obj = objs[0]

        # Replace other objects with instances of the original
        for obj in objs[1:]:
            # Create an instance of the original object
            instance_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(original_obj.name + "_instance", original_obj.data)
            instance_obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world

            # Link the instance to the scene
            bpy.context.collection.objects.link(instance_obj)

            # Unlink the duplicate object from the scene
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

# Run the script
selected_obj = bpy.context.active_object

if selected_obj and selected_obj.type == 'MESH':
    duplicate_meshes = find_duplicate_meshes(selected_obj)
    replace_with_instances(duplicate_meshes)
else:
    print("Please select a mesh object.")

As context, I have told Claude to ensure that transformations are applied (because the imported model is from Sketchup and resulted in a lot of odd behavior. I also told Claude to only detect meshes of the selected object in the scene.
Would appreciate if I could get some guidance on this, thanks :)

I think there was a similar question before, with an answer... I don't remember what it was, but you could for example generate a hash for something like a list of vertex coordinates. Then you could compare hashes and maybe make sure the meshes really are the same. Then you don't need instancing, you can just make objects reuse this mesh data. Instancing you can use to further decrease memory usage, but IMHO that's another problem: convert all objects sharing a mesh into instances.
